# TypeScript function input type changes when imported using alias import

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function like this

```
export interface Config {
    API_URL: string
    test2: string
}
```

```
import { Config } from "@types/config"

export const getWebConfig = <Keys extends keyof Config >(...keys: Keys[]) => {}

const test = getWebConfig("API_URL") // Works

const test = getWebConfig("API_URL", "asd") // Argument of type '"asd"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof InsourceConfig'
```

This works great for the use case I have. However I'm using a monorepo structure (Turborepo) and I currently export this via a barrel file.

Importing this to another file shows

```
const getWebConfig: <Keys extends keyof Config>(...keys: Keys[]) => Record<Keys, string>
```

When I import this into another package like so

```
import { getWebConfig } from "package-base"
```

It now has the type

```
const getWebConfig: <Keys extends string | number | symbol>(...keys: Keys[]) => Record<Keys, string>

const test = getWebConfig("API_URL", "asd") // No error
```

Interestingly, it works fine if the `interface Config` is directly imported, but when I use an alias import it gets this error.

I've tried typing this a few different ways and all of them seem to revert to `string | number | symbol` when doing this import. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `export type KeyOfConfig = keyof Config`, `export getWebConfig(arr:KeyOfConfig[])` ?  Just making a guess that breaking it down to smaller steps might help - don't know for sure.  Maintaining the key type manually would work, but yuck.

Comment: @CraigHicks I did try that and yeah seemed to come through with the same thing.

Comment: Did you try it in reverse - define the union of string keys then make an Object out of that?  E.f., `type K = "a" | "b";`, `type X = { [k in K]: string };`.  In the debugger you see `type X = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}`.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to export the Config object type, only the keys.  Then it will definitely work.

Comment: Hm yep interestingly doing something like `export type ConfigKeys = keyof Config` then using that in the function seems fine. Instead of `Keys extends keyof Config`